# How to create a popup to Speakker?

Tags: jquery, html

I have implemented [Projekktor Speakker](http://www.speakker.com/) in my site. I would like to create a popup which asks if you want to play music or not.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

---

**Edited:**

What I wanted to know is how to recall Speakker to my popup not how to create a popup!.. sorry if I wasn't clear!
I will open a separate question for this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 2):

**[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4PynD/1/)**

Basically create two `div` one is the `div` that will cover the entire background.
Second is the `div` which is your actual popup.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="mask"></div>
<div id="popup"><h2>Do you want to play music?</h2></div>​
```

**CSS:**

```
#mask
{
height:100%;
width:100%;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
background-color:#DDD;
z-index:100;

}
#popup
{
height:200px;
width:300px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
border:5px solid #FFAd08;
background-color:#FFD69C;
z-index:101;
position:absolute;
left:50px;
top:100px;
}
```

*Note:I have used styles just for demonstration you should style the popup as per your needs and position it the same way*

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

try this : pop will be open on page load

css

```
.mover {
    width: 250px; 
    height: 150px; 
    background:#000; 
    position:absolute; 
    border:1px solid #f5f5f5; 
    display:none;
    z-index:1001;}
```

script

```
   var myscreen=screen.width;
   var popPos =  (myscreen - 250) /2;   //250 is the width of popup
   $(function() {
    $(window).load( function() {
        $('#special').show();
        $("#special").css({
            marginLeft: popPos+"px",
        });
    });
    });
```

html

```
   <div class="mover" id="special"></div>
```